# How to use Memcached for session in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, session, memcached, laravel-5.7

Normally I used file as driver to store session and cache. Now I want to work with `Memcached` to store session and cache on Laravel 5.7 application. It is new to me. I have already installed `php-memcached` on my local environment.

In my Laravel 5.7 web application I have configured `session.driver` and `cache.default` in the `.env` file as following.

```
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```

I leave everything else with its default installation. When I refresh the page I get the following error.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Memcached' not found
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php 69
```

I do understand that when you configure driver for session and cache config to use `Memcached`, the `MemcachedConnector` will get involved. It imports the `Memcached` class and tries to create an instance object of the `Memcached` class as following.

```
use Memcached;

class MemcachedConnector {
    protected function createMemcachedInstance($connectionId) {
        return empty($connectionId) ? new Memcached : new Memcached($connectionId);
    }
}
```

With the above error, it seems like the `Memcached` class is missing. How can I solve it? Please do not tell me to do the following even it solves the problem.

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

or

```
SESSION_DRIVER=array
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Because I would like to use `Memcached` and would like to know what to do to make it work.

Comment: Did you install `php-memcached` or `php-memcache`? Beware that are two different extensions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.installation.php - check in particular that it's properly enabled in `php.ini`, by outputting `phpinfo()` in your Laravel app.

Comment: @dparoli I have install *memcached* due to a specific reason related to version, but I cannot remember of what the version was about, PHP 7.2 or Laravel 5.7. I forget about that specific reason, but know that I better use *memcached*.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so sorry for posting as answer.

Try running `php -i || grep 'memcached'` from your app directory.

If you're running vagrant, try `vagrant ssh` then `php -i || grep 'memcached'`

You could also (as suggested below) add `phpinfo();` to the top of your `routes/web.php` (underneath the `<?`) and that should spit out your php info when you try to load your site in the browser.

This will clue you up as to whether or not memcached is installed and loaded or not.

Comment: Note that the CLI and the webserver may have totally different `php -i` outputs. Better to do `phpinfo()` in the Laravel app on a route, so you can be certain you're getting the right one.